# WordPress sidebar не дружит со стилями css

Tags: php, wordpress, html, css

Делаю шаблон для вордпресса. Почему для файла sidebar.php не применяются стили, которые я прописываю? К примеру, название виджета в сайдбаре выводится через `h3.widget-title`, если я пропишу в css `h3.widget-title` или просто `.widget-title`, то ничего не меняется, стили не применяются.

Код css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    width:960px;
    color:#000
}

.widget-title{text-align:center; font-size:36px; color:#000} 

a{color:#c4c4c4; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; text-align: right;}


#logo{ background-image:url(images/blog_logo.png); width: 510px; height: 66px; margin-left:238px; margin-right:238 border:none;}
#menu-header{border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4; border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4; margin-top:5px; }

ul#items{list-style:none; list-style-type:none; list-style-position: outside; text-align:center; height: 15px; margin: 10px; padding:0}

ul#items li.menu-item a{padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; font-size:16px; text-decoration:none;}

#page{ width:960px; white-space:normal; height:auto}

#content{width:670px; height:auto; float:left; border-right: 1px solid #c4c4c4; white-space:normal;}

#sidebar{width:275px; float:right; height:auto; padding-left:10px; margin-left:0px; border-left:1px #c4c4c4 solid}

#container{width:660px; float:left; height:27px;} 

.post{width:660px; height:auto; float:left; width:670px; padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4; margin-bottom:5px;} 

.post h1, #full_post h1 { color:#c4c4c4; font-size:18px; margin:0; width:670px; padding-top:15px; border-bottom: 1px dashed #c4c4c4;}

.post h1:hover, #full_post h1:hover {color:#000;}

.post p, #full_post p{ width:660px; margin:0; padding-top:10px;}

.post .metabar{width:660px; border-top: 1px dashed #c4c4c4; color:#c4c4c4; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:2px; text-align:center; margin-top:15px;}

.more-link{padding-left:15px}

.page_nav_header{float:left; width:670px; height:auto; padding-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4}
.page_nav_footer {float:left; width:660px; height:auto; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px}

.left{text-align:right; width:100px; height:auto; float:left;}

.right{text-align:left; width:100px; height:auto; float:right; margin:0; padding:0;}

#footer {width:959px; height:auto; border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4; clear:both; padding-top:5px; font-size:12px}

.copy{float:right; text-align:right; width:960px}

#full_post{width:670px; float:left; border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4}

.page_nav_header_fullpost {float:left; width:670px; height:auto; padding-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px}

#full_post #likebar {width:670px; height:auto; border-bottom:1px #c4c4c4 solid; border-top:1px dashed #c4c4c4; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:2px; padding: 5px 0 5px 0;}

#full_post #metabar{width:670px; border-top: 1px dashed #c4c4c4; color:#c4c4c4; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:5px; text-align:center; margin-top:15px;}

#full_post #info_rss{width:670px; height:auto; text-align:center;  border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4}

#full_post #info_rss::first-letter {font-size:20px; color:#c4c4c4}

#full_post #comments {width:665px; height:auto;}

#full_post #respond {width:670px; height:auto}
```

Код из файла sidebar.php:

```
<div id="sidebar">
 <?php dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar') ?>
</div>
```

---

Comment: а как подключено ? через стандартные теги WordPress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмтрите какие CSS таблицы подключены к HTML документу отправленному сервером браузеру, поищите в этих таблицах  "h3.widget-title" если такого селектора нет, стало быть css не подключается, если есть - возможно этому элементу назначенны еще стили которые имеют более высокий приоритет, тут поможет инспекция документа, по умолчанию стоит в опере, chrome.

Comment: Нею и проверяю. Там показывает что только применяются стили по дефаульту. Мои же стили чего то не применяются. В этом и есть суть моего вопроса. Как сделать так что бы они заработали.

Comment: В вашем шаблоне для вордпресс значит просто подключите css файл и все, хотя в этой CMS есть способ добавлять в переменную php имя css таблицы и она будет добавляться к уже подключенным

Comment: css подключается в шаблоне через header.php, думаю подключать ещё раз css в sidebar.php не имеет смысла.

Comment: Описывайте стили в уже подключенных таблицах значит!!!! Не работать не может!

Comment: Говорю же, описывал. Не работает.